# Grouping objects with lodash or ES5

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, typescript, lodash

I'm a javascript noobie, I started to use the library lodash and I'm having some problems. Can someone help me? :/

Input:

```
var a = [{group: 'A', title: 'test1', value: 'test2'},
         {group: 'A', title: 'test2', value: 'test3'},
         {group: 'B', title: 'test3', value: 'test4'},
         {group: 'B', title: 'test1', value: 'test2'},]
```

Output:

```
var a = {A: [
         { title: 'test1', value: 'test2'},
         { title: 'test2', value: 'test3'}
        ],
         B: [
         { title: 'test1', value: 'test2'},
         { title: 'test2', value: 'test3'}
        ],}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lodash documentation for group by is pretty explicit you can find it [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy).

In your case it would look something like this.

```
_.groupBy(a, 'group')
```

You can also do it yourself pretty easily as well using the **reduce** function. It would look something like this:

```js
let groups = a.reduce((grouping, currentItem) => {
    if (!grouping[currentItem.group]) {
        grouping[currentItem.group] = []
    }
    grouping[currentItem.group].push(currentItem);
    return grouping;
}, {});
```

A working example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20a%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20group%3A%20'A'%2C%20title%3A%20'test1'%2C%20value%3A%20'test2'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%20group%3A%20'A'%2C%20title%3A%20'test2'%2C%20value%3A%20'test3'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%20group%3A%20'B'%2C%20title%3A%20'test3'%2C%20value%3A%20'test4'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%20group%3A%20'B'%2C%20title%3A%20'test1'%2C%20value%3A%20'test2'%20%7D%2C%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20groups%20%3D%20a.reduce((grouping%2C%20currentItem)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!grouping%5BcurrentItem.group%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20grouping%5BcurrentItem.group%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20grouping%5BcurrentItem.group%5D.push(currentItem)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20grouping%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B).

In both cases the result would be an object with the groups as property names.

```js
{
  "A": [{
    "group": "A",
    "title": "test1",
    "value": "test2"
  }, {
    "group": "A",
    "title": "test2",
    "value": "test3"
  }],
  "B": [{
    "group": "B",
    "title": "test3",
    "value": "test4"
  }, {
    "group": "B",
    "title": "test1",
    "value": "test2"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group with [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) and then use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) on each group to remove the `group` property from the objects by mapping them to a new object using [`_.omit()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit).

```js
const a = [{group: 'A', title: 'test1', value: 'test2'},
         {group: 'A', title: 'test2', value: 'test3'},
         {group: 'B', title: 'test3', value: 'test4'},
         {group: 'B', title: 'test1', value: 'test2'}
       ];
       
const result = _(a)
  .groupBy('group') // group by the group prop
  .mapValues((group) => group.map((o) => _.omit(o, 'group'))) // remove the group prop from each item
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```